# Старый коммит отвязался от ветки origin/master. Как его туда вернуть?

Tags: git

Старый коммит под названием Start отвязался от ветки master.
(Оба коммита по задумке должны быть на главной ветке).
Попытался перейти на главную ветку и из неё написать git cherry-pick cd891d6, но гит начал ругаться. Я в гите новичок, подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне коммит start вернуть на главную ветку?

Ссылка на репозиторий
https://github.com/boluchevskii/englishmakerNEW

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В гите коммиты не привязываются к веткам, а наоборот, ветки привязываются к коммитам. Посмотрите историю у убедитесь, что "отвязавшийся" коммит является предком коммита, на который указывает ветка master.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2 изучайте документацию. Как минимум первые 3 главы

Comment: @user7860670 смотреть историю не нужно. Есть готовые команды, которые сразу скажут ответ на вопрос про commit ancestor. Еяпп, это у `git branch`.